# Saving battery life on the Lumia 610

Tags: lumia, battery

My parents just got the Nokia Lumia 610, and I've set it up using the same "battery saving" features I have on my N8 - power saver automatically goes on, changed connection from 3G to E, screen dims and locks after 30s, etc etc. However, they do nothing on the phones (they don't browse, download, check email, take photos). I've installed WhatsApp (which they hardly use), which I suspect is draining the battery, because the phone lasts from 6am (charged fully) until about 4pm.

I know its a basic phone, which is perfect for them ("I only need to receive calls and smses!"), but surely the battery should last at least a day, especially if they are barely using it? Are there any other default settings which I could change to help enhance battery life?

Comment: What about the polling frequency? increasing it from the default value of 3 will help or not?

Comment: Where would I change this setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Go to Setting, Swipe to go to the applications tab. Select background tasks and turn off every background task which you don't require.
2) Don't use applications like flashlight and others very often which may drain your battery. 
3) Keep your WiFi and Cellular data off when not in use. 
4) Turn on battery saver. 
5) Set brightness to automatically adjust.
6) Disconnect find my phone feature in settings page.
7) Screen time out should be minimum.
8) Avoid leaving applications on which run under lock screen or do not allow the phone to lock automatically after screen time out.
9) Reduce push email frequency (Settings -> email+accounts -> select account -> Download new content)
10) Turn keypad tones off 
11) Make sure you are not listed as available (Me->Set chat status -> offline) (by Ivan)

These are some of the methods to optimize your battery usage. If there are any other which I find, I will update it here. Also looking forward to other ways of battery saving methods for WP7.

**Update**

Found this [link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/battery-making-it-last) at windowsphone website. Covers most of the things.

**Update**

Whatsapp uses an audio api to remain connected or do most of its stuff in the background, so using whatsapp may have significant impact on battery performance.

Also if not required, prevent or limit use of vibration both in the phone and in apps.

Comment: Had everything in place besides number 1 and 6, but apparently my mother had used the radio and instead of exiting it, it was running the whole time, same with my dad and the music player. Sigh. There should definitely be improved battery life now! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.. :)

Comment: Worth noting that WiFi is automatically disabled by the OS whilst the screen is locked, so that doesn't save as much power as you'd at first think.

Comment: yep thats true.

Comment: Also phone on Vibration uses battery more...

Answer (score 2):

If I can add to the list Milan posted. Make sure you are not listed as available (Me->Set chat status -> offline)

This might help you as well to save a few hours :)

Comment: Can you edit Milan's answer and add this in there so we have one definitive list? thanks!

Comment: Don't have such privileges... It will have to be done by some of the admins

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić anyone can propose an edit, someone with rep will approve it for you. You'll even gain 2 rep when it's approved

Comment: ans has already been edited. I have included the above point too :)

Comment: For some reason I haven't see the edit button. That's why I have assumed I have no rights but now I am able to see it :) The most important thing is that it's the answer is there and is visible for others :)